# Can I import org.eclipse.jdt.core into Netbeans?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, netbeans, module

I am using a [this](https://github.com/aametwally/Halstead-Complexity-Measures) project on the project that I am developing in Netbeans. Basically, I copied the 3 source code files to my project and did some tweaks to the `Main.java` file in order for me to be able to use it in my project.

The compiler then said that `package org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler does not exist` for the following imports:

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.IProblem;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
```

I tried to add the module dependency by going to `Project Properties` > `Libraries` > `Module Dependencies` > `Add` and typing `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler` but no library was found. Usually, the available libraries are shown as one types their name. In this case, none was shown.

So, I downloaded `org.eclipse.jdt.core` jar from [here](https://jar-download.com/?detail_search=a%3A%22org.eclipse.jdt.core%22&a=org.eclipse.jdt.core) and added it to the project by going to `Project Properties` > `Libraries` > `Wrapped JARs` > `Add JAR`. The compilation errors disappeared and I was able to run the project.

However, when the line `ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);` is reached, the following exception is thrown.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource

I am supposing that this exception and the fact that I couldn't find the library in the module dependecies in Netbeans are related.

Does this mean that I cannot use `org.eclipse.jdt.core` in Netbeans or is there another problem? Can someone help me?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/, since the useful part of the exception text is missing, i.e. the name of the class that wasn't found.

Comment: You did of course remember to add the `org.eclipse.jdk` jar file to the classpath at *runtime*, right?

Comment: @Andreas I noticed that I had a typo on my post. I said that I downloaded org.eclipse.jdk by mistake. Actually, I downloaded org.eclipse.jdt.core. And yes, I remembered to add the jar to the classpath by going to `Project Properties` > `Libraries` > `Wrapped JARs` > `Add JAR`. That was when the compilation errors disappeared. So that is not the problem. Any idead on where else can it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the Eclipse ASTParser in a plain (non-OSGi, not Eclipse-based) Java application you need following JARs:

- org.eclipse.core.contenttype
- org.eclipse.core.jobs
- org.eclipse.core.resources
- org.eclipse.core.runtime
- org.eclipse.equinox.common
- org.eclipse.equinox.preferences
- org.eclipse.jdt.core
- org.eclipse.osgi
- org.eclipse.text

All these JARs can be found in an Eclipse SDK ZIP file that you can download from the [Eclipse Project Downloads](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) website, e. g. [Eclipse 4.7.3a SDK](https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.7.3a-201803300640/#EclipseSDK). Since these JARs are not platform-dependent, it doesn't matter which operating system you choose. For example, you can choose [eclipse-SDK-4.7.3a-win32-x86_64.zip](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.7.3a-201803300640/download.php?dropFile=eclipse-SDK-4.7.3a-win32-x86_64.zip).

In the ZIP file, you will find the JARs in the subdirectory `plugins` as `<id>_<version>.jar` (the corresponding source code as `<id>.source_<version>.jar`).

Comment: Great explanation! Solved my problem. Thank you very much!