# How to fix the NoClassDefFoundError while using AstParser in Eclipse using Java Swing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am working on code refactoring techniques for which i have to used `AstParser` an Eclipse plugin for the identification of methods and classes my Java file but it is giving an exception in thread `AWT-EventQueue-0`: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource error`

```
private CompilationUnit parse(String fileName) {        
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setSource(getChars(fileName));
    CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
    return cu;
}
```

I want to parse the Java files but the following code snippet continuously giving me the error I am in very trouble because it is my final year project.

Comment: [These JARs are required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50311348/6505250). By the way, `AST.JLS3` is deprecated and with this you cannot parse Java 1.6 or higher.

Comment: its alternative

Comment: are you sure about it....?

Comment: Yes, I use it myself that way. `IResource` is indirectly required. Make sure to add all the mentioned JARs to your classpath to avoid the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: ok thanks bro for your kind words

Comment: howlger please can you guide me how to import this sdk that you mention in the link in eclipse

Comment: Download [this ZIP](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.11-201903070500/download.php?dropFile=eclipse-SDK-4.11-win32-x86_64.zip) and use the [`plugins/*.jar` files that are listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50311348/6505250).