# How to instantiate org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit or org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

**What I am trying to do**

I use the Eclipse JDT API to create the AST of some java project and manipulate it, however, my software is not an Eclipse Plug-in but it's supposed to be a stand-alone desktop application.

Right now in order to use a specific method of the API, I need an instance of org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit. 
As far as I understood this code snippet would do that:

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(); 
IPath path = Path.fromOSString(stringPath);
IFile file = workspace.getRoot().getFileForLocation(path);
ICompilationUnit compilationUnit =(ICompilationUnit)JavaCore.create(file);
```

The problem is that `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()` won't work, I **guess** because my application is not Eclipse Plug-in. The specific Exception that is raised is the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:432)
```

**What I need**

The solution that I would like to implement involves making the folder in which the source code is contained in an Eclipse Workspace (provisionally).

Therefore, I need a way to get an instance of org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace given the path of the folder in which the source code is contained, basically:

```
String path = "./folder/with/source/code";
Workspace workspace = pathToWorkspace(path);
```

N.B. btw if there is a way get an instance of an ICompilationUnit, without the need of a workspace, that also would solve my problem.

**What I have tried**

What I have tried to do is create an instance of ResourcesPlugin and make it start with the hope that through BundleContext I would be able to specify the path. Unfortunately, org.osgi.framework.BundleContext is an interface which is specified that is [not supposed to be implemented](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html) by the consumers and I wasn't able to find a concrete class that implements this interface.

```
ResourcesPlugin plugin = new ResourcesPlugin();
plugin.start(boundleContext);
```

Comment: You are going to really struggle to do any of that. Writing a headless Eclipse RCP which will have ResourcesPlugin set up properly is the way to go.

Comment: The Eclipse Java Compiler can also be used outside of Eclipse, e.g. in a plain Java application. [These Eclipse plug-in JARs are required for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50311348/6505250).

Comment: Have a look at my Blog Post: https://jmini.github.io/blog/2020/2020-01-17_jdt-without-eclipse.html. I am using JDT example inside JUnit tests in projects built by maven. There are 2 projects one requiring OSGi (using bnd maven plugins to achieve this) and on standalone (simple maven project).

Answer (score 0):

What is the specific method you need to use?

You could try:

```
AST ast = AST.newAST(AST.JLS16, false);
CompilationUnit unit = ast.newCompilationUnit();
```

then add to the unit:

```
//with package:
PackageDeclaration pd = ast.newPackageDeclaration();
pd.setName(ast.newSimpleName("example"));
unit.setPackage(pd);

//class:
TypeDeclaration type = ast.newTypeDeclaration();
unit.types().add(type);

//and so on..
```