# Access Eclipse JDT Root Workspace without Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

My goal is to get access to a `jdt.core JavaProject` without running the plugin in eclipse but as a standalone project. 
This code should work when using a plugin (When accessing a workspace to load and create projects):

```
ResourcePlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
```

Which throws a `Workspace is closed` error since I am running this plugin without eclipse thus a lot of initialization from eclipse is missing.

Is there a way to this initialization manually instead of having to run it through eclipse? This way I would be able to complete my goal of executing a plugin as a standalone.

Comment: Writing an Eclipse 'headless RCP' is  the only reasonable way to use Eclipse resources in a non-GUI app.

Comment: I wonder why you need an `IJavaProject` in a standalone application. To [parse and compile Java code an `IJavaProject` is not required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50311348/6505250).

Comment: Because the plugin I want to implement as a standalone requires an IJavaProject

Comment: @HashTableView So it is required because it is required?! [_"IJavaProject - Represents a Java project in the workspace."_](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_int_model.htm?cp=3_0_0_0) and the workspace and projects make use of Eclipse extension mechanism which in turn requires the extension registry, which is implemented based on OSGi. So either your standalone application is a headless Eclipse-based (RCP) application or you get rid of using `IJavaProject` and other workspace-related things.

Comment: If you need a Workspace in to run your code based on JDT, the "initialization" step correspond to run the code inside an OSGi runtime. I have a maven based setup running example usage of the JDT inside JUnit tests. There are 2 distinct projects depending if you need OSGi or not: https://jmini.github.io/jdt-experiments/#programcreek-examples