# ASTVisitor class definition not found in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I am new to Eclipse and I am trying to use the ASTVisitor class. I have added then jar `jdt.core` file to my referenced libraries and other required jars. I added the jars from the plugins installed with Eclipse inside the `C:\Users\nemo\.p2\pool\plugins` folder.

I am getting the error message below:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class parsers
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTVisitor
```

imported class are:

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodInvocation;
```

I also get this message `Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.` when I hover my mouse over each of the imported class line.

added jar files are:
[image: all jars added]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50311348/6505250 (the sources are in the corresponding `... .source_ ...` JARs).

Comment: @howlger Looks like the answer is for NetBean IDE. I am using Eclipse

Comment: It is my answer and this list of JARs works for me in Eclipse and should also work for other Java IDEs as well.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: I fixed the issue by installing the version of eclipse "Eclipse IDE for Java and DSL Developers". I added the plugin jars to the build part from the .p2 folder. Not sure may be it a bug with the "Eclipse IDE for Java" version

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by installing the version of eclipse "Eclipse IDE for Java and DSL Developers". I added the plugin jars to the build part from the .p2 folder. Not sure may be it a bug with the "Eclipse IDE for Java" version